# Reconstruct orthogonal from an orthostochastic matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Given an $n \times n$ orthostochastic matrix $\mathbf{A}$, i.e., there exists an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{O}$ with $A_{ij} = O_{ij}^2$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$. What is the fastest way to find $\mathbf{O}$ from $\mathbf{A}$?

As the missing information is only the signs, a complete search over all sign patterns would solve the problem. However, this involves testing $2^{N^2}$ sign patterns. The number of sign patterns can be reduced slightly by some equivalence operations like sign inverting a row. Also, there are $\textit{sign patterns allowing orthogonality}$, i.e., collection of all sign patterns which occur in orthogonal matrices. Besides that the characterization of sign patterns allowing orthogonality is still open for $n > 6$, it will probably not reduce the number of possible candidates to a polynomial magnitude.

There is an analogous case of reconstructing unitary matrices from unistochastic matrices. There is some literature on the analytic side like "The Importance of Being Unistochastic" by Bengtsson, I. (2004). However, I am more concerned with an efficient algorithmic solution to this problem. Any ideas?

A local improvement can be achieved by the following: given $\mathbf{A}$ and a random $\pm$ sign matrix $\mathbf{S}$. Then we can find the closest orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{P}$ by solving the Procrustes problem $\min \lVert \mathbf{P} -
 \mathbf{A} \circ \mathbf{S} \rVert_F$ with the singular value decomposition, where $\circ$ is the Hadamard product. If now, $\textrm{sign}(\mathbf{P}) \neq \mathbf{S}$ then we can improve by solving with replacing $\mathbf{S}$ with $\textrm{sign}(\mathbf{P})$, because $\mathbf{A}$ is non-negative. This works until the sign matrices are equal.

Comment: I have some doubt that this could be done efficiently. A reconstruction process would also make a decision whether a bistochastic matrix is orthostochastic (rare) or not. The orthostochastic matrices form an $n(n-1)/2$-dimensional subset in the $(n-1)^2$-convex set of bistochastic matrices. I am not sure that it has a nice, external description.

Comment: Note that the proper definition of orthostochastic is that $a_{ij}=|u_{ij}|^2$ where $U$ is unitary. Then the set of orthostochastic matrices is of positive volume in the polytope of bistochastic matrices, although it is strictly smaller if $n\ge3$.

Comment: @DenisSerre Thanks for the comment on the definition. My impression was that your definition refers to unistochastic matrices, but there are differences in literature.

Comment: @DenisSerre I agree that it seems unlikely to find something efficient, however, I believe it is possible to help an algorithmic solution. For example, it is possible to improve local solutions by solving iteratively the Procrustes problem.

Comment: A few questions: Are we interested in an algorithm which works well for a random orthostatic matrix, or for one chosen by an intelligent adversary? How are the entries are $A$ given: rational/algebraic numbers in closed form? Floating point approximations?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer The algorithm should work well on random orthostochastic matrices which are given in floating point approximations.

Comment: For example, there is Hadamard matrix of order $n$ if and only if the $n \times n$ matrix whose every entry is $1/\sqrt{n}$ is orthostatic. Finding Hadamard matrices is a quite difficult problem. Am I supposed to solve it, or is it okay if this considered an unusual case and my method doesn't have to handle it?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Right, finding Hadamard matrices is indeed hard. As this is all not very easy, I would be already happy to find a good (not optimal) solution in terms of the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. By the way, typo above: I should have asked for $A_{ij}=1/n$, not $A_{ij}=1/\sqrt{n}$; I missed that you squared the entries rather than taking absolute value.

Comment: I suspect I am not going to have a good idea but, let me ask: How does the error $\delta$ in your floating point numbers compare to the size $n$ of your matrices? I was going to suggest doing a back-tracking search column by column, where you use off the shelf heuristics for multiple-subset-sum to find candidates for each column. (I can spell out more.) But back of the envelope computations suggest this is only significantly better than brute force if $n^3 \delta^2$ is small.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer As the exhaustive search over all sign matrices breaks down for very small matrix sizes (n > 12), I believe that typical 32bit double precision is no issue.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer I am very much interested in your back-tracking idea. I will also add my local improvement method to the question. Maybe it helps to determine the direction.